# Progress bar not responding on button click. I hv created a progress bar with value 10 and when user clicks on button value should get change to 20

Tags: salesforce1-app

HTML

```
<lightning-progress-bar value={prop} size="large">
   </lightning-progress-bar>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" label=" load" onclick={handleClick}>
 </lightning-button>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ProgressBarBasic extends LightningElement {

  prop=0;

  handleClick(){

   this.prop =20;

   console.log(this.prop)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple typo its **onclick** not **onlick**

Change it as below

```
 <lightning-button variant="brand" label=" load" onclick={handleClick}>
```

Comment: thanks issue solved.